# Invoke BAT with Java and save the enviroment(changed by the BAT) to pass the enviroment to the next BAT

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

i have the following problen.

Let's say a have two BAT-Files called b1 and b2:

b1 is setting an ENV:  `set hello=hello`

b2 is echoing/printing this ENV: `echo -- %hello% -- >> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hello.txt`

Now, i like to Invoke b1 and b2 throw JAVA and let b2 echoing hello based on the value of `%hello%`.

If I do this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c call C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\b1.bat").waitFor();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c call C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\b2.bat").waitFor();
```

I get this output in the hello.txt:

```
-- --
```

It seems that the information is lost between the two calls. Could someone help me?
Thanks!!!

Comment: one obvious way is to write the data in a temp file that will be red from the second bat file.

Comment: Just execute the two Batch files under _the same_ cmd.exe, so the environment be preserved: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c call C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\b1.bat & call C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\b2.bat").waitFor();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, i found a solution. 
I generated a new bat-file( b0 ) and invoke the others. 
So this code helps me.

b0.bat Code:

```
call b1.bat
call b2.bat
```

Java-Code:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c call C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\b0.bat").waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment is only inherited from parent process to child process. So whatever is set by b1.bat is lost when b1.bat ends (so neither your java process nor b2.bat will see an environment variable set by b1.bat). And of course these won't be visible to any other process your java code could launch.

If you want to set environment variables for your child processes, you should use ProcessBuilder to execute them (so you can set specific environment variables before starting them).